# HTML from XML for WebBrowser control vs WPF dynamically generated interface

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wpf, winforms

There is an application showing some data from a large amount of sources. So that tables is grouped on some number of tab pages of TabControl. Each tab page has a WebBrowserControl that is needed for rendering HTML document generated by XSL transformation from XML based on data retrieving from DB. Such architecture was founded instead of many GridView controls, due to performance issues.

That application continues to grow and I think maybe there are more rational way to achieve necessary result. I'm aware that WPF, which become popular recently, is based on XML (it's almost all that I know about WPF). So I think about ability dynamically generate interface from XML without translation into HTML for a WebBrowser control, is it possible? Has such approach the real advantages?

More details: I have about 10 tab pages. Most of them contain 5-10 tables (with some or some hundreds rows). Some pages should to contain an interactive graph or diagrams. Now retrieved from DB data have to be put into trees of XML document like:

```
<table name>
<row columnname1 = "data1" columnname2 = "data2" .../>
...
</table name>
```

Then such XML documents are transformed by XSL into correct  HTML structures.
And then the 's are put into XSL that describes the tab page HTML structure - so I get correct HTML document with tables, for example, that WebBrowser control shows.

Comment: Yes. WPF is much more powerful than anything else currently in existence. XAML (the XML-based language used to define WPF UIs) is much more powerful and scalable than HTML. putting HTML in a non-web application seems like a hack to me, whereas WPF is the preferred technology for .Net Windows Applications.

Comment: But I'm not sure if WPF can effectively render XML getting at run-time or XAML just defines generation of source code at compile time?

Comment: XAML gets compiled into BAML in WPF, but you can also load XAML from an external source and render it on the fly at runtime. Anyways, it would be better that you show some of the XML you're talking about, or at least an example of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: BTW, You can also do this with regular WPF UI instead of trying to create the UI on the fly. WPF has built-in [UI Virtualization](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D3Y6DnFpHCA) and it supports big loads of data without losing performance. Please, edit your question and add more detail, and I can tell you the best approach.

Comment: What kind of details should I add?

Comment: it is not clear what type of XML you're talking about, and how does your UI look like. I'm pretty sure you can create a normal WPF application to achieve whatever you need without resorting to any type of runtime-XML-conversion or the like. Just getting pure data from a DataBase or Web Service and displaying it in a WPF application is a fully supported scenario.

Comment: That XML looks like the definition of DATA, rather than UI, I don't understand why you need to generate a UI dynamically for this instead of just defining a regular UI at design time and DataBinding to these results.

Comment: As to WinForms my predecessor had tried do it with GridView's and data binding to collections, but it worked slow.

Comment: winforms is horribly slow. it doesn't support anything, and it does not support databinding to large collections of data. you will not have this problem with WPF. Check the "UI Virtualization" link in my previous comment.